# Esconder botón tras x segundos desde inicio de app

Tags: java, android

Me gustaría que en mi app de android un botón solo estuviera disponible durante x segundos. El problema es que todas las soluciones que he visto lo hacen después de hacer click o algo similar, pero a mi me gustaría que fuera x segundos desde que se abre la app, sin que el usuario tenga que hacer nada para ello.

He usado esto pero la app se queda en blanco y no muestranada en el logcat:

```
class Hilo extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(200000);
            MainActivity.boton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

En MainActivity hago:

```
Hilo ocultar = new Hilo();
            ocultar.run();
```

**EDIT** 
En MainActivity hago:

```
Hilo ocultar = new Hilo();
            ocultar.start();
```

Comment: Puedes hacer Thread.sleep(tiempo_en_milisegundos) lo cual te bloqueará la ejecución del hilo principal durante el tiempo que le indicas o creas un nuevo hilo y lo ocultas desde ahí. Con esto último no bloquearás la ejecución del hilo principal.

Comment: Seguramente te esté dando un error por intentar acceder a un control del hilo principal desde otro hilo. Cambia el InterruptedException por Exception a ver si te caza la excepcion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ocultar.run()` ejecuta la tarea en el mismo hilo. Utiliza `ocultar.start()` para ejecutar el metodo `run()` en un nuevo hilo.

**EDIT**

Hazlo de la siguiente manera.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button hiddeMe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hiddeMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hideMe);

        Thread hiddeThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(200000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            hiddeMe.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    // El hilo fue interrumpido. Maneja el error como desees.
                }
            }
        });

        hiddeThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo he probado así también pero al pasar el tiemppo de espera se para la app

Comment: @pepito Lo que pasa es que solo puedes llamar a `View.setVisibility()` desde el hilo del *UI*. Puse un codigo que funciona, probado.

Comment: Así es, tu código ha funcionado a la perfección. ¡Muchísimas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tienes :

```
 MainActivity.boton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

asegura de obtener la referencia del botón en tu layout mediante su id, posteriormente puedes cambiar sus propiedades, como en este caso la visibilidad:

```
Button boton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPepito);
boton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //esconde botón.
```

---

**Esconder botón tras x segundos desde inicio de app**

Puedes usar varias opciones, entre estas, el uso de un Handler para llamar un proceso después de n milisegundos, como ejemplo este proceso que llamarías al inicio de tu aplicación, en el método `onCreate()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //en 10 segundos , hace invisible el botón.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                  boton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //esconde botón.

            }
        }, 10000); //10 segundos;
        ...
        ...
}
```